# Insert data to multiple tables in Create View ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm trying to insert data to two tables in a `Create View`. What I have is a table `User` and another table `WorkingHours`. The `WorkingHours` table defines the hours each `User` works in a week. I'd like to be able to add the user's `WorkingHours` at the same time you're adding a user, so it has to be the same `View`. I've been looking through examples how to do this, mainly working with `PartialViews`.

I've followed this [example](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/fe1c187c-9d93-4c48-89dc-e497c2a53294.aspx) to insert the data both to the `Users` and `WorkingHours` tables.

These are the classes of each table (I'm working **Model First** here):

**User**

```
namespace Common
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.WorkingHours = new HashSet<WorkingHours>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<WorkingDay> WorkingDays { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**WorkingHours**

```
namespace Common
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class WorkingHours
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> WeekDay { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> HoursFrom { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> HoursTo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've added two **Partial Views** for User and WorkingHours:

**User Partial View:**

```
    @model Common.User

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
</div>
```

**WorkingHours Partial View**

```
@model Common.WorkingHours

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WeekDay)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WeekDay)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WeekDay)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HoursFrom)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HoursFrom)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HoursFrom)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HoursTo)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HoursTo)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HoursTo)
</div>
```

**Partial Views Combined:**

```
@model Common.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "User", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.Partial("_UserCreate")
    @Html.Partial("_WorkingDayCreate", new ViewDataDictionary()
        {
            TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo()
            {
                HtmlFieldPrefix = "WorkingDay"
            }
        }
    )

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
}
```

When creating the user, the object does have the user details...Name, Surname etc. but not the `WorkingHours`, the list remains `null`. I thought adding `ViewDataDictionary` would solve the issue but the list remains `null`. Not sure if this works differently with a list rather than an object as shown in the link above.

**UPDATE**

I might solve the issue by passing a `User` object to the `View` in the `Create` method.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    User u = new Common.User();
    return View(u);
}
```

And populate the `WorkingHours` list in the `User` constructor.

Comment: Can you post the resulting HTML as well as your action?

Comment: Mind that in both partial views you import the same js libraries, you shouldn't do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by passing a `User` object to the `View` in the `Create` method.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    User u = new Common.User();
    return View(u);
}
```

I'm populating the `WorkingHours` list in  the `User` constructor:

```
// Monday to Friday (0 to 4 - using an enum: DaysEnum), default hours 08:00 to 17:00
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    this.WorkingHours.Add(new WorkingHour
    {
        WeekDay = i,
        HoursFrom = 8,
        HoursTo = 17
    });
}
```

In this case this makes sense as the list has default values for each day.

Answer (score 0):

Change partial's model to `User` and render editor like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkingHours.HoursFrom)
```

Comment: Since `WorkingHours` is set as a list in the `User` class I cannot access the `WorkingHours` properties

Comment: Try implement your form without partial. Then we'll talk about extracting workinghours into partial

Comment: Yep, that's what I've done :) Posted an answer as well